# MS Access + OLAP

Tags: ms-access, olap

I have lot of data in MS Access, and for analysis I need tools. Might you suggest any tools for data mining and analysis (OLAP)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your data volumes the the complexity of the relationships that you want to investigate:

(1) Moderate volumes with low complexity relationships - use queries, pivot's graphs and reports in ms-access.

(2) High volume and or high complexity relationships - consider up sizing to SQL server and using the more grown-up data cubes (OLAP), stored procedures etc.

Comment: It's not "upgrading" to SQL Server, but "upsizing."

Comment: David - upgrade changed to upsize

Comment: Midle complexity. I have to calculate several numbers, and after that analyse accoding dozen criterias. It is really easy to calculate those numbers in the Access, but analysis according criterias it is pain.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a few of the analysis criteria and explain why you are finding it "a pain" to do in ms-access

Comment: 'Upsizing' is just a marketing term. 'Upgrading' seems correct to me because SQL Server is a more capable SQL product.

Answer (score 2):

Support for Access (and other various non-SQL Server data sources) will be included in the upcoming SQL Server 2008 R2 release (this release is focusing on self-service BI).  You can follow how the project is progressing at [http://blogs.msdn.com/gemini](http://blogs.msdn.com/gemini/).

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution can be Excel 2010 using the new Power Pivot Add-on.
It really depend on the type of analisys needed.

Federico

Answer (score 1):

I guess your best bet would be to import your data into SQL Server using SQL Server Integration Services - should be pretty straightforward and painless.

Once in SQL Server, you have the **[Analysis Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522607.aspx)** at your disposal which give you all these capabilities for OLAP analysis.

I don't think there's much for MS Access directly.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

If it is not too much data, import it into Excel and use the privot table functionality.

If it is too much for that then SQL Server is the way to go.

Comment: More then 700,000 records. It is not for excel :(. I don't have licenses for SQL Server, so looking for other solutions

Comment: You could try Active Reports http://www.datadynamics.com/?utm_source=DNR&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=DNRAR

Answer (score 0):

An alternative OLAP solution is to use [icCube](http://www.icCube.com) to connect directly to your MS Access file.